# How asynchronous request processing works in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, spring-mvc, asynchronous

i have a problem understanding asynchronous processing

I've read about DeferredResult and everywhere there is information that it is asynchrnous
because it allows to unblock http thread and delegate processing to worker thread.

My question is how is that beneficial? We create new thread just to release existing one?